# Displaying an int in a char, with some modifications

Tags: c, string, pointers, char, printf

I'm currently converting a Csharp programme into Unix C. It's running well, except:

I have an integer (secs) containing a number of seconds that, for aesthetic reasons, I want to display with front zero (1->01, etc). The code I've cooked up is below, and it sometimes works, and sometimes doesn't, depending on where it's called. I suspect the problem is with the pointer.

```
char *st_str;
if(secs<10)
{
   if(secs==0) st_str = "00";
   else if(secs==1) st_str = "01";
   else if(secs==2) st_str = "02";
   else if(secs==3) st_str = "03";
   else if(secs==4) st_str = "04";
   else if(secs==5) st_str = "05";
   else if(secs==6) st_str = "06";
   else if(secs==7) st_str = "07";
   else if(secs==8) st_str = "08";
   else if(secs==9) st_str = "09";
}
else
{
   sprintf(st_str,"%i",secs);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sprintf() to st_str, you have to allocate memory for it. However, the code you've come up with is absolutely superfluous. Why don't you just use the `%02d` format specifier? Also, `sprintf()` is generally considered insecure, please use `snprintf()` instead:

```
char st_str[3];
snprintf(st_str, sizeof(st_str), "%02d", secs);
```

Note that if you want to return `st_str` from a function, you can't use an auto array, but you should instead write

```
const size_t size = 3;
char *st_str = malloc(size);
snprintf(st_str, size, "%02d", secs);
```

Answer (score 1):

The code will experience undefined behaviour when the `sprintf()` is called as `st_str` is an uninitialized pointer. `st_str` needs to be pointing to valid memory.

However, to print a leading zero use format specifier `"%02d"`. For example:

```
char st_str[32];
snprintf(st_str, sizeof(st_str), "%02d", secs);
```

and avoid the `if/else`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove that big if/else construct and replace with:

```
sprintf(st_str, "%02d", secs);
```

Your version isn't working because `%i` expects an int and you're feeding it a pointer to char. You could "fix" it with `%s`, but that's way too much work you're doing for something the standard function can do for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can just put the zero in a format string and use `sprintf(...)`:

```
sprintf(st_str,"0%d",secs);
```

Notice now that since you can generalize all seconds from 0-9 in the same statement, a switch statement might be more appropriate:

```
str_str = malloc(<max-digits-here>);

switch(secs) 
{
   case 0:
   case 1:
   case 2:
   case 3:
   case 4:
   case 5:
   case 6:
   case 7:
   case 8:
   case 9:
      sprintf(st_str,"0%d",secs);
      break;
   default:
      sprintf(st_str,"%d",secs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this below:

```
if(secs >=0 && secs < 10)
 sprintf(st_str,"0%d",secs);
else
 sprintf(st_str,"%d",secs);
```

Or if you only want to display use `printf("%02d",secs)` and directly print that to output screen.

EDIT : But remember is case of `sprintf` you must have allocated memory for `st_str` to keep the value of `secs`.

Answer (score 0):

Why convert it to a string at all. `printf` can display the number with padding

For eg.

```
int secs;

for(secs = 0; secs < 60; ++secs)
    printf("%02d\n", secs);
```

Or if you want it in a string

```
char s[20];
snprintf(s, 20,"%02d", secs);
```

Comment: I think it should be `<=59`

Answer (score 0):

To print a minimum of `n` digits, you can use the precision point in the formatter, like this:

`printf("%.2d", secs);`

You don't need to create a character variable etc etc!